# Modifying Values of row values while iterating over dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I have this dataframe test_data:

```
  Deal    Year    Month     Billing   Running_total   payment    over_payment

2   A      2018   December  21167.99    21167.99      1270.08       0.00
3   A      2018   December  -3184.59    17983.40     -1270.08       0.00
4   A      2019   January   1855.10     19838.50      0.00      -1270.08
5   A      2019   February  400.00      20238.50      0.00          0.00
6   A      2019   March     600.00      20838.50      0.00          0.00
7   A      2019   April     1000.00     21838.50      0.00          0.00
```

I want to keep passing the negative amount in over_payment down to the next row as long as 6% of the Running_total is less than the absolute value of -1270 until the point where 6% of the Running_total is greater or equal to the absolute value of over_payment then set that value of over_payment to 0. I have to execute the code below four times before I get the correct output, I think it must be an issue with setting the next row value of over_payment before the iteration even reaches that index #.I'm trying to do this on a "Deal" level which is why I included a condition where the next deal name has to be equal to the current one so it doesn't carry over to Deal "B" for example, and only performs changes to the relevant Deal.

Here's what I have tried:

```
 for index, row in test_data.iterrows():
   if row['over_payment'] <0:
     if (row['Running_Total'] * .06)>abs(row['over_payment']):
       test_data.at[index, 'over_payment']= 0
       test_data.at[index, 'Rebate']= (row['Running_Total'] * .06) + (row['over_payment'])

     elif (row['Running_Total'] * .06)< abs(row['over_payment']):
       next_index= str(int(index) + 1)
       last_index= str(int(index) - 1)
       if test_data.at[index, 'Deal'] ==test_data.at[next_index, 'Deal']:
         test_data.at[next_index, 'over_payment'] = test_data.at[index, 'over_payment']
       else:
         test_data.at[index, 'over_payment'] = test_data.at[last_index, 'over_payment']
```

Desired Output:

```
Deal      Year    Month     Billing   Running_total   payment    over_payment

2   A      2018   December  21167.99    21167.99      1270.08       0.00
3   A      2018   December  -3184.59    17983.40      -1270.08      0.00
4   A      2019   January   1855.10     19838.50       0            -1270.08
5   A      2019   February  400.00      20238.50       0            -1270.08
6   A      2019   March     600.00      20838.50       0            -1270.08
7   A      2019   April     1000.00     21838.50       40.23            0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that gets your desired answer in a single try:

```py
for deal in test_data.Deal.unique():
    over_payment = 0  # reset for each deal
    for idx, row in test_data[test_data.Deal == deal].iterrows():
        if row.over_payment < 0:
            over_payment = row.over_payment
        elif over_payment < 0:
            if row.Running_total * 0.06 < abs(over_payment):
                test_data.loc[idx, 'over_payment'] = over_payment
            else:
                over_payment = 0
```

There are a couple of assumptions that are being made here. The first is that the index is unique. The second is that the data is in order of date. Both of these are easily managed, you just have to be aware of them.

Also I don't see what you're doing with `'Rebate'`, as that's not in your Desired Output. I also don't know what issue you're having with looking forward and back a row. I avoided this by working on one row at a time, and just keeping the state of the last row, resetting it as necessary.

Comment: thank you so much this works perfectly. I was trying to do with "Rebate" was if (row['Running_Total'] * .06) > (abs(row['over_payment'])) then add 6% of running_total to the overpayment amount, thats how I got 40.23, do you know how I can add this into your answer? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, just right after the `else:` add a line that says `test_data.loc[idx, 'Rebate'] = round(0.06 * row.Running_total + over_payment, 2)`